# How to detect resume or leave?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

how to determine when to screen resume or leave when using Getx?
Ex: Product screen -> Cart screen. On Cart screen I remove 1 product and go back to Product screen, I want to update cart quantity badge on UI but I don't know how?
Is there a way to be detectable like onResume()?
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score -1):

The same way the author of GetX package made a [sample counter app](https://pub.dev/packages/get#counter-app-with-getx) you can make your own app logic.

Create a CartController that extends GetxController and inside place your 'cartProductQuantity' integer variable and make the variable observable placing .obs at the end of it.

```
class CartController extends GetxController{
  var cartProductQuantity = 0.obs;
  increment() => cartProductQuantity++;
  decrement() => cartProductQuantity--;
}


class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(context) {

    // Instantiate your class using Get.put() to make it available for all "child" routes there.
    final CartController c = Get.put(CartController());

    return Scaffold(
      // Use Obx(()=> to update Text() whenever quantity badge is changed.
      appBar: AppBar(title: Obx(() => Text("Items: ${c.count}"))),

      body: Center(child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Go to Other"), onPressed: () => Get.to(Other()))),
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: c.increment));
  }
}


class Other extends StatelessWidget {
  // You can ask Get to find a Controller that is being used by another page and redirect you to it.
  final Controller c = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(context){
     // Access the updated count variable
     return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("${c.count}")));
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not relate to the question.